# Navigate tab to a URL and execute script inside

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am struggling to get this simple f-ty working... My scenario is:

1. get current URL
2. modify it
3. navigate/redirect to it
4. execute custom JS code there

The most problems I have is with 4)

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Hello, World!",
  "description": "Navigate and execute custom js script",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {}
}
```

background.js

```
function myCustomScript() {
    alert('myCustomScript test ok!');
    console.log('myCustomScript test ok!');
}

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {

    chrome.tabs.update({url: "https://example.com"}, myCustomScript);

});
```

The page got redirected but my js function is not executed! Do you know why and how to fix it?

P.S: this is my first time I am creating my chrome extension, maybe I am doing something wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute custom code, use [chrome.scripting](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/) API. For this scenario you'll need:

1. `"scripting"` added to `"permissions"`, which you already have,
2. `"https://example.com/"` added to `"host_permissions"` in manifest.json.

Note that `activeTab` permission won't apply to the tab after it's navigated to a URL with a different origin because this permission only applies to the currently shown origin.

**Due to a [bug in Chrome](https://crbug.com/1191971), you need to wait for the URL to be set before executing the script**.

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async tab => {
  await chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: "https://example.com"});
  // Creating a tab needs the same workaround
  // tab = await chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://example.com"});
  await onTabUrlUpdated(tab.id);
  const results = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    files: ['content.js'],
  });
  // do something with results
});

function onTabUrlUpdated(tabId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const onUpdated = (id, info) => id === tabId && info.url && done(true);
    const onRemoved = id => id === tabId && done(false);
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(onUpdated);
    chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(onRemoved);
    function done(ok) {
      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(onUpdated);
      chrome.tabs.onRemoved.removeListener(onRemoved);
      (ok ? resolve : reject)();
    }
  });
}
```

P.S. `alert` can't be used in a service worker. Instead, you should look at [devtools console of the background script](/a/10258029) or use [chrome.notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications) API.

Comment: for some reason it says: "Service worker registration failed"... even if I leave chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async tab => {})(); from all your code - it shows the error...

Comment: There was a typo: `()`. Sorry about that. The answer is updated.

Comment: what version of chrome do you have?

Comment: The current version is 92.