# Chrome Scripting API: can not inject script

Tags: typescript, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I am working on chrome extension. I use typescript and webpack. My host_permissions in manifest.json are set up for "https://*/*". Manifest's version is 3. Currently, script that being injected just has alert in it.

Whenever I try to inject script on [www.instagram.com](http://www.instagram.com) - it doesn't work. But, **when injected on [www.tiktok.com](http://www.tiktok.com) - everything works** and i can see an alert. My guess is that something is maybe wrong with permissions? Attaching my manifest.json, and the code that injects script (btw, in both cases i can see console.log message from cb function).

**Manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Fan Base Inst Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "scripting",
        "storage",
        "downloads"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

**Injection code:**

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: url, active: true }, async (tab) => {
    const tabId = tab.id;
    if (!tabId) {
        console.error('Failed to create tab for:', url);
        return;
    }

    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tabId },
        files: ['soundScraper.js']
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('Injected soundScraper.js');
    });
});
```

**Injected script:**

```
alert('Script is injected');
```

Comment: UPD: i have just discovered that it also doesn't work on googl.com

Comment: Looks like a bug in Chrome. Try the old workaround: [Navigate tab to a URL and execute script inside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68611306)

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes it worked!!! Omg, thank you, i was thrilled by that for the whole day! May you publish it as an answer?